# firebase onAuthStateChanged following Fibonacci's series

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an hybrid app using Ionic 3 and Firebase as authentication provider. The app consist in 2 pages. A login page and an home page. On the login page there's a button that log-in the user using email+password and on the home page another button logout the current user. Basically, the first time the app is loaded everything works fine. But after loggin-in then logging-out then logging-in again the function inside onAuthStateChange gets called twice, then three times, then five and so on following the Fibonacci's series.
This is the login page code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log('User logged-in');
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          self.goToHome();
        } else {
          self.showAlert();
          firebase.auth().signOut();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is the logout code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user == null) {
          console.log('User logged-out');
          navCtrl.push(WelcomePage);
        }
      });
```

chrome console shows this behavior:

(the error at the end of the image was my fault as I used the wrong password)

[image: Chrome console showing the functions getting called following the Fibonacci series]

The functions called by the buttons (but I'm 99% sure that the problem is onAuthStateChanged):

```
  doLogin() {
    console.log('Trying to log in...');
    var email = this.account.email;
    var password = this.account.password;
    if (this.validateEmail(email) && password.length >= 8) {
      loading.present();
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function(data) {
        loading.dismiss();
       });
}

logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
```

The function goToHome to move the user to the homepage:

```
goToHome() {
    this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
  }
```

> Solution as pointed out by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464693/7932010) in his comment:

1: moving all navController related functions from onAuthStateChanged
2: using setRoot instead of pop() and push()

```
goToHome() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
logout() {
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(WelcomePage);
}
```

3) To fix be able to auto-login the user if he/she didn't logout I check 
   if firebase.auth().currentuser exist, but using a timeout because 
   Firebase needs some time before functioning properly:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user != null) {
          self.goToHome();
        }
      }, 1500);
```

Comment: Please also mention your `component` route logic. what this do `self.goToHome();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are pushing pages in your `onAuthStateChanged`. Which can cause a problem.

1. On the first Login page you create 1 `onAuthStateChanged login` when you click login you PUSH 1 new home page
2. On the Home page you create 1 `onAuthStateChanged logout` when you click logout you PUSH 1 new Login Page (so you have 2 Login Pages & 2 `onAuthStateChanged login` loaded after click)
3. After clicking login on the new Login Page you don't create 1 new Logout Page, but 2 because you already had 2 `onAuthStateChanged login`, so this results in 3 Logout Pages loaded and 3  `onAuthStateChanged logout`
4. When you click logout on the new home page, you call the 3  `onAuthStateChanged logout` and thus create 3 new login pages + 2 existing login pages = 5
5. And so on.

To test if this is the case, you can start loading your Module with the login page, when you login you PUSH the home page and when you logout you DON'T push the login page but [popToRoot()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Using `popToRoot()` solved half of the problem. Basically now I have one instance of WelcomPage but I'm still getting multiple istances of HomePage. So the problem is inside the logout.

Comment: Strange, but good one half is already solved, how many times does the HomePage get instantiated? also Fibonacci like?

Comment: The homepage behaves just as before, meaning instantiating following the Fibonacci series, but at half the increase than before

Comment: Edit for the above comment: Now that I re-checked now the fibonacci's series has stopped and it's just a +1 increment when logging-out.

Comment: I expect there is still a problem with your push, as the popToRoot cancels the weird behavior and the push starts it again. Can you try changing the push Home & poptoroot to: this.navCtrl.setRoot(MainPage); & this.navCtrl.setRoot(WelcomePage); to see if the inception stops?

Comment: Using setRoot and removing any navigationController invocation from onAuthStateChanged solved the problem! Thanks. Still I don't completely understand why everything happened.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the user to the page after the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, not on the listener. Firebase listeners have a weird behaviour...

Try this:

```
doLogin() {
    console.log('Trying to log in...');
    var email = this.account.email;
    var password = this.account.password;
    if (this.validateEmail(email) && password.length >= 8) {
        loading.present();
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(data) {
            loading.dismiss();
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if (user) {
                console.log('User logged-in');
                if (user.emailVerified) {
                    self.goToHome();
                } else {
                    self.showAlert();
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                }
            } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            }
        }, function(error) {
        //error handling
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this solution too but this way the user has to authenticate every time he close the page

Comment: Once you init the application and are going to the landing page, verify if the user is already there, if so, no need for asking credentials...

Comment: Alredy tried this way but firebase need some time to initialize so I'd need wait x time before checking if the user is already there, and this doesn't seem an elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my login. The function/listener `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(` will trigger every time the authentication state changes, I expect the problem in your `onAuthStateChanged` code is with `firebase.auth().signOut();` which will trigger a new `onAuthStateChanged` ... resulting in weird inception behavior.

You already placed `firebase.auth().signOut();` in your logout button and I suggest you remove `firebase.auth().signOut();` from the `onAuthStateChanged` on the login page, then I expect the Fibonacci would stop (but do you really want it to stop?)

Let me know if this gets any result. Hope it helps,

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem because the signout() is called only if the email isn't verified, which isn't the case

Comment: Hmm, maybe another problem: I see you are pushing pages, first pushing Login Page (compiling the first onAuthStateChanged, then pushing Login Page (which doesn't destroy the previous Login Page), which then pushes the Welcome Page again (=Login Page?) which initiates the second onAuthStateChanged ... when you login again you call the 2 onAuthStateChanged which will push 2 Home Pages, When you logout on that page you push 1+2 (1 from the first & 2 new ones) Welcome pages on which you create 2+3 User Login ... Resulting in a Fibonacci sequence

Comment: I changed `this.navCtrl.push(WelcomPage)` into `this.navCtrl.pop()` but now the app crashes when the series start because after calling `pop()` the first time the second time ionic finds no page to pop. But you're right saing that pushing instead of popping is wrong, still onAuthStateChanged creates problem..

Comment: See my new solution below, in summary: you can start loading your Module with the login page, when you login you PUSH the home page and when you logout you DON'T push the login page but PopToRoot